# How can I install numpy exactly without root access on server?

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, pip

I want to install numpy on a server without root access. I have installed pip, but when I try `pip install numpy` I get an error.

```
Command /home/wanglan0605/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_wanglan0605/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-gb9EVf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_wanglan0605/numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wanglan0605/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/wanglan0605/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/wanglan0605/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 70: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What should I do next? Please give me some idea

Comment: As i can see the problem i don't think it is not because of the root access. You  have an error in the input args.

Comment: could you show me which input args I made wrong? I do not understand at all

Comment: is this when you run `pip install numpy`? Are you using a virtual-enviroment? Have you pressed anything while installing the numpy? Because i reproduce this error when i pressed `Control-C`.

Comment: No I did not do anything. I have tried many times pip install numpy but it does not work

Comment: You can always use Anaconda from continuum. It is free.  https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a lot of ways to install python libraries. The most effective way to install python libraries without root access is [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/). just use `wget` command and `bash  Anaconda-2.1.0-Linux-x86.sh` and then press yes two or three times. After finishing that, all of the packages commonly used can be installed exactly. 
This is really a more convenient way than installing those packages respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Is it [this bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1137)?

> Any non-ASCII character in the log causes PIP to crash with UnicodeDecodeError.

There is a [patch suggested by remram44 on github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1137#issuecomment-23613766), and this worked for me when I encountered a similar error before.

Comment: It also says /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lptf77blas but what is that

Comment: Where does it say that? I'm not sure I know how to fix your problem, but I also recommend using [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) instead (like @mrcl above), and it should be able to be installed without root access.